# How to change format of a GridView field from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle

I can show a GridView with the data I need from code behind like this:

```
SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = "select * from table"
```

However I have a date field, which done like this gets displayed as 12/03/2012 12:00:00 a.m. for example. When done on ASP it can be fixed like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="DATE" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yy}" HeaderText="DATE" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DATE" />
```

However I'm using only code behind. If I try to use the BoundField for date I get 2 date columns, and if I dont add the date field to the select statement then I get no date at all.

So anyway I can do this from code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not to familiar with asp.net, but you can always change the format in the sql query:

```
select to_char(<your_date_column>, 'dd/mm/yy') "DATE" from table
```

But aren't you supposed to do it in the IIS in `Globalization - colture` ?

Comment: @user1676874, Sorry my mistake I ment `to_char` not `to_date`. Fixed my answer - check it now

Comment: Nope, I get this error: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'DATE'.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140245/changing-gridview-column-properties-from-code-behind) you can use below code:

```
BoundField dateField = new BoundField();
dateField.HeaderText = "Date";
dateField.DataField = "date";
dateField.DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}";
gridView.Columns.Add(dateField);
```